# maximizing profit for given stock data via DP

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

You are given the stock prices for a set of days . Each day, you can either buy one unit of stock, sell any number of stock units you have already bought, or do nothing. What is the maximum profit you can obtain by planning your trading strategy optimally?

Now the answer can be obtained through single pass but what if it has to be solved through Dynamic Programming. What will be the recurrence relation then for the problem?

I think for any day `OPT(i)` can denote maximum profit earned so far, so one has to sell all remaining shares on the last day so

```
OPT(i) = max (
         Sell all on this day bought from day j to day i + OPT(j-1), 
         OPT(i-1) + do nothing)?
```

Is this right?

Comment: What is this? homework?

Comment: Why would you use a bazooka where a simple revolver will suffice...

Comment: What would be the single-pass solution?

Comment: Hint: What should you do on the day with the highest stock price?  What should you do on the previous days?  What does the rest of the problem look like after doing this?

Comment: @TimothyGroote: No it is not but I am curious to know the recurrence relation.\

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I have given a try at answer listed in my question. highest price? Isn't recurrence relation meant to explore all solution space?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Sell all on this day bought from day j to day i" -- it seems that this could be anywhere from 0 up to j-i stock items, depending on what decisions were made.  In any case, your solution doesn't explore the complete solution space either: it only considers O(n^2) solutions, while there are O(2^n) in total.  Still, *if* you can prove that no possible solution can be better than one of the O(n^2) that you do consider, then it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve like this:

dp[i][j] means the maximum profit you get while you are still holding j units of stock.

Then

```
dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j-1] - cost, //buy one unit
               dp[i-1][j], // do nothing
               dp[i-1][j+1] + profit // sold one unit
               dp[i-1][j+2] + 2*profit //sold two units
               ...
               )
```

then find the maximum value of dp[N][j] (0<=j<=MAX)

The time is (number_of_days * total_stock_you_can_buy^2)